# Autoclick a button to open a pop-up

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to automatically open a pop-up on my site after for example 5 seconds. So I decided to auto-click on the button which opens the pop-up. So I tried to use : document.getElementById('button_id').click(). However my method doesn't work.. Do you see a problem in my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('button').click()
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg button" type="submit" id="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquirypopup">SUBSCRIBE</button>
</div>
```

Maybe is there an other way? With something like .show() with my pop-up?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you call the function that **opens** the modal instead?

Comment: Also, what does "doesn't work" mean? Does it throw an error? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: Nothing happen, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the bootstrap's inbuilt function for triggering the modal

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myModal").modal();

});
```

`#myModal` is the id of the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

The html like:

```
<div id="popup-div-id">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#popup-div-id
{
     position:fixed;
     z-index:3000;
     top:50px;
     left:50px;
     display:none;
     background-color:red;
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      setTimeout(function(){

           $("#popup-div-id").show();
      },5000)
}
```

So full page like:

```
  <html>
     <body>
         <div id="popup-div-id">
         </div>

         <style>
              #popup-div-id
              {
                  position:fixed;
                  z-index:3000;
                  top:50px;
                  left:50px;
                  display:none;
                  background-color:red;
              }
         </style>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>

             $(document).ready(function(){

                   setTimeout(function(){

                         $("#popup-div-id").show();
                    },5000)
              }               

         </script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Nothing happen too. Maybe I put my <script> in a wrong place? Where do I have to put it?

Comment: Now take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#mymodal').trigger('click');}, 5000); 


});
```

**OR**
for this remove `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquirypopup"`

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg button modalpopup" data-target="enquirypopup" type="submit" id="button">SUBSCRIBE</button>

$(document).ready(function(e) {

     setTimeout(function() {
        $('#enquirypopup').modal("show");}, 5000); 


     $("body").on("click",".modalpopup" , function(){
       $("#'+$(this).attr('data-target')+'").modal("show");
     });        

    });
```

Comment: If I remove 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquirypopup"' the visitor won't be able to manually open the pop-up anymore...

Comment: @LoïcKreseski i have updated my answer as well but i would like to prefer to first method i have mentioned